# Ruby on Rails 6 can't deploy to heroku with webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, webpacker

I upgraded my app to RoR 6, which included using webpack. I previously was using React-Rails, with the components in the asset pipeline, but now my file structure looks like this:

```
app
  assets
  controllers
  javascript
    components
    packs
      application.js
    src
config
  webpack
    development.js
    environment.js
    production.js
etc...
```

Everything works fine in dev, but when I try to push to heroku, it's been constant issues for days. I've tried everything  I can find online, and I just need some fresh eyes.

Currently, the build is failing saying `Can't resolve './src' in '/tmp/build_70fb951d'`. Everything I can find online suggests adding an `entry` to the config file, pointing to `javascript/packs/application.js`, but it doesn't seem to change the error.

```
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build (yarn)
remote:        yarn run v1.22.10
remote:        $ webpack
remote:        [webpack-cli] Compilation finished
remote:        assets by status 0 bytes [cached] 1 asset
remote:        
remote:        ERROR in main
remote:        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/tmp/build_70fb951d'
remote:        
remote:        webpack 5.6.0 compiled with 1 error in 198 ms
remote: error Command failed with exit code 1.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
```

Here is my config file:

environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}));

module.exports = environment
```

production.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

I've also tried this:

environment.js (I also tried the bulk of this in production.js, but same error)

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}));


module.exports = environment => {
  mode: environment,
  entry: './app/javascript/packs/application.js',
  output: {
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/'),
         filename: prod ? "[name].bundle.js" : "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  optimization: {
           splitChunks: {
           chunks: 'all',
           },
   },
}
```

production.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "== README",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.3-4",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.3-4",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.9",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lottie-web": "^5.4.2",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "progressbar.js": "^1.0.1",
    "rails-ujs": "^5.2.4-4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
 }
```

Any new suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the biggest waste of time, and I'd delete the question, but hopefully this answer will help save someone else time.

The solution was to add a folder called `src` and an empty file in that folder named `index.js`

So here is a sample of my file structure:

```
app
bin
config
db
src
  index.js
lib
```

`index.js` is empty except a small comment:

```
//This file solves a bug deploying to heroku. Do not delete
```

[This post](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6858) and [this post](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6890) helped me find this solution.

Once I got this working, I had moved and changed so many things, I needed to rerun `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` because now I was getting this error:

```
Webpacker can't find application in <my app path>/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

[This post helped me solve that.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/997)

Now everything is working properly!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Webpacker 5, the ruby step of your deployment expects `webpack-cli` to have been installed and thus for the `webpack` binary to be available. First check your installed buildpacks, specifically their **order**

```
heroku buildpacks --remote staging
=== beamstage Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/ruby
2. heroku/nodejs
```

If `heroku/ruby` comes before `heroku/nodejs` then you need to swap them around because the order of the buildpacks does indeed determine the order in which your dependencies are installed. Ruby first means `bundle install` as well as `rake assets:precompile` goes before `yarn`. The only way I could find to swap was to remove them both then add again:

```
heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/nodejs [--remote <staging|production>]
heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/ruby [--remote <staging|production>]
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs --remote staging
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 heroku/ruby --remote staging
```

Comment: Lol your solution solved my problem and this is documented nowhere else on the internet. Thank you stranger